# Replicate Data in the inserted rows

Tags: vba, excel

The code below automatically inserts specified rows in the Excel Worksheet, I need this code to also replicate the data from only some cells in the inserted row from the previous row. In, other words, in the data (image attached), the code below adds blank rows above the active cell. What I also need is the code to replicate the data from Columns `Sales_ID` and `Sales_market` into the inserted rows.

[image: Screenshot of Worksheet]

e.g. If I am adding rows above Customer 4 (highlighted in yellow in the data), the code would replicate the `Sales_ID 1234` and `Sales_market Canada` into the inserted rows. The other cells for Customers and Customer_ID in the inserted rows should be blank.

```
Sub Multiplerows4()
  Dim rng As Integer
  Dim k As Integer
  Dim rRange As Range

  Set rRange = Selection

  rng = InputBox("Enter number:.")
  For k = 1 To rng
    Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified version of code with help from Parfait that is working for my purposes -

```
Sub Multiplerows()
Dim rng As Integer, k As Integer
Dim rRange As Range
Dim salesID As Long, salesMkt As String

Set rRange = Selection
rng = InputBox("Enter number:.")
For k = 1 To rng
    Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
                            CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next k
   For k = rng To 1 Step -1
Cells(rRange.Row - k, 1) = Cells(rRange.Row, 1)
Cells(rRange.Row - k, 2) = Cells(rRange.Row, 2)
   Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: To be fair, this is very, very close to my own with removal of `salesID` and `salesMkt`. Sometimes in SO posted answers will not *exactly* work since OPs give mock data for demo and leave out sensitive info but if it is 95% the same, surely it is an answer, especially as I show the process of looping backwards.

Comment: Parfait - I really appreciate your help and I am not saying that this is solely my effort. You code example helped me figure this out. I modified my response above. Also, the mock-up data that I provided is exactly the same data I have. I don't believe that I left out any sensitive info. Anyways, you are free to post the modified code as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a second backwards stepping loop to update the inserted rows. Below assumes `Sales_ID` and `Sales_Market` are in the first and second columns (adjust accordingly):

```
Sub Multiplerows4()
    Dim rng As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim salesID As Long, salesMkt As String

    Set rRange = Selected

    salesID = Cells(rRange.Row, 1)
    salesMkt = Cells(rRange.Row, 2)

    rng = InputBox("Enter number:.")
    For k = 1 To rng
        Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
                                CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next k

    For k = rng To 1 Step -1
        Cells(rRange.Row - k, 1) = salesID
        Cells(rRange.Row - k, 2) = salesMkt
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, Parfait. Its giving me this error - "Run time error 424" ; Object Required for this line of your code -  Set rRange = Selected

Comment: If I change "Selected" to "Selection" , I am not getting error for that part but the code is not entering the rows, and also giving an error - Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: I almost asked about that one line as you do not define it posted snippet. Try explicitly setting the range as one cell or multiple (which I did in building the answer): `set rRange = Range("A3:B10")`

Comment: Parfait, I am not sure why your code is not working. Its not adding row above the selected cell. I, however, modified your code as this - `
   For k = rng To 1 Step -1
    Cells(rRange.Row - k, 1) = Cells(rRange.Row, 1)
    Cells(rRange.Row - k, 2) = Cells(rRange.Row, 2)` and it worked great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you resolve `Selection`? Why not explicitly put a range or wherever ActiveCell is located. I just opened a brand new workbook and placed first three lines of your data with headers in `A1`. My answer works as does yours. All you did was remove need of VBA variables: `salesID`, `salesMkt`.

Comment: Parfait - I did not include specific range because the range can be changed with updated data and I want the rows to get inserted before my active cell.

Comment: Try using `set rRange = ActiveCell`. Removing sales variables forces Excel to re-calculate `rRange.row` twice with each iteration. This line is why code does not work as I do not know what you are selecting.

Comment: Thanks much, Parfait for all your help and suggestions.